# Limit a boolean to a server (Discord JDA)

Tags: java, discord, boolean, discord-jda

How can I limit a boolean to one server?

If I use a normal boolean to create a command that can be disabled: `Boolean b = true`
and make it changeable with a text command:

```
if (event.getMessage().getContentStripped().equalsIgnoreCase("message")) {

            if (event.getMember().getPermissions().contains(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)) {

                if (b) {

                    b = false;

                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Successfully disabled the command.").queue();

                } else if (!b) {

                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("The command is already disabled.").queue();

                }
```

it gets disabled/enabled for all servers the bot is in. I want people to only disable it for their own server though. How can I do this?

Sry if it's easy. I haven't found anything on Google. I'm not so experienced with coding yet. I'm here to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of state per-guild you can use a [map datastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), with the guild's ID as key.

```java
private final Map<Long, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can then *store* the boolean using `map.put(guild.getIdLong(), false)` and later *load* using `map.get(guild.getIdLong())`. Note however, that this will not persist between program restarts, since it is only stored in memory. To persist this state, you have to use a database, such as SQLite or similar.